# Aluminium rigid fork for winter

Tags: fork, winter, aluminum

I'm looking for the bike for winter riding and found [this one](http://format.bike/catalog/city/format-5341-2018/).

It's all good, except for the fork: some people say that aluminum rigid forks can not absorb vibration and therefore are bad for the winter 'cause there's firm snow and ice, which is not smooth at all.

So, are they right and I have to look for steel or carbon fork? (I'd really like to use rigid one for the winter)

Comment: You should probably decide what *winter* means where you are. How much snow/ice? But to be honest you can ride pretty rough roads on a hybrid with rigid forks (I have been known to take mine on fire roads, then onto trails bouncing over tree roots etc.), so it would have to be very bad; the forks wouldn't be the worry then

Comment: @ChrisH Saint-Petersbourg in Russia. This winter is really snowy - i'ts already a knee deep. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you are looking for a cheap bike to ride in harsh winter conditions. The advertised price of 35,960₽ is about US $615 (at the time the question was asked) which would be considered a quite inexpensive bike here.

Your choice or tires is going to make a much bigger difference than a carbon fiber vs aluminum fork. An aluminium fork will be fine, but look for a bike with clearance for bigger tires.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I'm looking for an inexpensive bike with less maintenance needed than my gt avalanche - this is why I'm looking for a bike without the rear derailleur.

Comment: @k102 I'm a year-round commuter in Canada and I'll give you an alternate view: winter riding destroys bikes, especially drive trains. I ride a fully-rigid steel single-speed bike with fenders and remove one brake. I replace the chain every spring and the rest of the drive-train every 2-3 years. Save your good bike for the summer and treat winter bikes as consumables!

Comment: @markd - that's why I'm looking for this one. Used one is not an option since I can refund some from company I work for, but only for the new one. So - I'd like to have a single speed chain

Answer (score 2):

I assume you would use the bicycle in the city. In this case, a suspension fork does not make much comfort difference compared to a rigid one — there are no roots or rock gardens in St Petersburg. It will make even less difference in a deep snow when all terrain features are smoothed by it, and you cycle slower than usual because the ground is more slippery and treacherous. I would definitely go with a rigid fork (no matter what material). In terms of comfort, I would also go with the widest tires possible.

Comment: This is one time I'd avoid steel.  That bike will be wet for months, except when it's frozen.

Comment: @ChrisH fair point. However, I used a full steel bike in very similar winter conditions for several years. Given that the bike spent half of the every working day in an outside bike parking but was stored in a dry apartment and cleaned thoroughly on a regular bases, I cannot see any rust damage outside/inside, especially at the fork which is easier to inspect inside than a frame.

Comment: The propensity of steel to rust is vastly exaggerated.

Comment: Is steel rusted so badly, why are all the bridges in the world still standing and why are all the ships int he world still floating on the high seas?

Comment: Both of them are regularly repainted and are designed to lose some material to rust. Ships also have sacrificial anodes to reduce corrosion in hull. But yes, steel bikes don't really rust that badly.

Comment: I dont' know about St. Petersburg, but Helsinki often has slush that is treaded into irregular blobs that then freeze solid afterwards. I would compare it to rocky trails, except slippery as heck.

Comment: @ojs - very similar to Helsinki, yes. And those blobs is the main reason I'm asking this question)

Comment: So, I have to look for wider tires clearance and then decide about the rest. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRHicks having seen a new cromo bike start to show signs of rust in 6 weeks where the paint job wasn't up to spec, I'd still be careful when buying a new bike specifically for wet conditions.  On the other hand I make a habit of running old steel bikes that are kept outdoors

Comment: @ChrisH -- There's a difference between "showing rust" and being structurally compromised due to rust.

Comment: @DanielRHicks true. But you've also got to consider loss of value (and even, for some people, aesthetics), as the OP is talking about getting a new bike. As a measure of my position, I don't keep my steel tourer for a fair weather bike by any means, but I try not to commute on it in the wet too much, so it doesn't sit wet (especially on the bits I can't see)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some one will see this question:
I've bought an aluminum rigid fork (some no-name brand) and to test how it feels went on an xc race on that bike. There was quite a lot of snow and bumps.

As I've expected I was quite fast on the uphills, but slow on descends - I was feeling that there's limit (for bumpy xc trail) somewhere around 30 km/h - if I try to go faster, I immediately loose control over the front wheel.

But for the city riding purposes this fork is a great thing, I have no regrets and like the look.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Aluminum has about 1/3 the modulus of steel , so will elastically strain 3 X more with the same load. I don't know if that makes a difference for absorbing shock on a bicycle. And aluminum also has 1/3 the strength of steel ( depending on heat treatments) so will plastically deform ( fail ) at 1/3 the load of steel. Proper painting the steel will essentially eliminate rust in these mild conditions.  Wiping with an oily rag will also greatly reduce rust on bare steel. Bare steel bridges, etc , are normally "weathering "steels ;containing small amounts of P , Cu, Cr , etc .

Comment: Aluminum also has 1/3 the density of steel, so aluminum parts are typically designed with larger dimensions and thicker walls. The result is often an equally strong and stiffer structure at slightly lower weight.

Comment: Al must be 3 times thicker to be the same stiffness.

Comment: This is why aluminum parts are designed with larger dimensions too. Check out the math under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bending_stiffness and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area.